# Change datetime format in variable

Tags: php, datetime

Lets say I have this variable =

```
$olddate = 12-5-99 15:30:00
```

and I would need a new variable like =

```
$newdate = 1999-5-12 15:30:00
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just you can change it like.

```
<?php
   $olddate = '12-5-1999 15:30:00';
   $olddate = date('y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($olddate)); // first convert it in desire formate.
   $newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($olddate));
?>
```

Comment: You can get the running example [here.](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/h5v-b7x)

Answer (score 1):

DateTime::createFromFormat will allow you to convert any format of time into a DateTime object, which can subsequently be output as any *other* format.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: +1 but an example would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime() and date():

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

(see strtotime and date docs on the PHP site).